# Sustituir todos los campos NULL de una tabla a 0 SQL Server

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Saludos a todos, tengo una tabla  que contiene alrededor de 97 campos. Sé que seleccionando los campos y agregando funciones como Coalense, isnull ó null; se pueden convertir a 0. Sin embargo mi pregunta esta un poco compleja. ¿Hay alguna forma de identificar en la tabla todos los campos que contienen nulos y a su vez sustituirlos por 0?

Aclaro que algunos campos tienen nulos y números, es decir, vienen los datos revueltos.

```
----zonas
    declare @temporalzonas  table(
        unitsysid varchar(20), 
        licenseplate varchar(50),
        zona varchar(30),
        cedis varchar(30)
    ) 
    insert @temporalzonas 
    exec sp_unidades_operativas_femsa   
    --select * from @temporalzonas
---------------------------------------------

-----------TELEMETRIA
    declare @TemporalTelemetria table
    (
        zona varchar(35),
        cedis varchar(35),
        udidlog varchar(15),
        tclientes int,
        tvisitados int,
        tnovisitados int,
        validacion_cliente varchar(50),
        clientes_fin_firma_entrega int,
        cajas_sin_firma int,
        cajas_entregadas int,
        cajas_rechazadas int,
        validacion_caja varchar(30),
        tcajas int,
        total_cajas_validacion int /*,
        validacion_cajas varchar (50)*/
    )

    insert @TemporalTelemetria

    select zona,
           cedis,
           udid,
           tclientes, 
           tvisitados, 
           tnovisitados, 

           (case
                when tclientes = tvisitados then 'Visito todos los clientes'
                else 'No completo las visitas'
            end) 
            validacion_cliente,

            clientes_sin_firma_entrega, coalesce(cajas_sin_firma,0) cajas_sin_firma,
           cajas_entregadas, 
           coalesce(cajas_rechazadas,0) cajas_rechazadas, 

           (case
                when (cajas_entregadas + (isnull(cajas_rechazadas,0)) + cajas_sin_firma) = tcajas then 'Correcta' 
                else 'Validar caja'
            end        
           )
           validacion_caja,


           tcajas,
           (cajas_entregadas + coalesce(cajas_rechazadas,0)) total_cajas_validacion        
    from Telemetria 
           inner join @temporalzonas on 
            unitsysid = udid
            select * from @TemporalTelemetria
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a hacer un update en esos campos que contienen nulos?

Comment: Ahhh, sí disculpas por no ofrecer mayor información. La tabla de la que estoy hablando la estoy insertando en una tabla temporal para poder realizar cálculos sin afectar la tabla original. Me gustaría efectivamente primero actualizarla (todos los campos de la tabla) y proseguir con mis cálculos.

Comment: Talvés si nos muestras tu código será más fácil identificar lo que deseas lograr :D

Comment: Les muestro la pantalla.

Comment: Me refería a que pongas en texto lo que deseas logar, es decir, el script donde está tu tabla temporal así como el resultado que deseas obtener. Además recuerda etiquetar la pregunta con el motor de base de datos que estás utilizando.

Comment: Esta muy largo el código, por ese motivo les solicitaba alguna idea. Pero, se los muestro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que todos los campos son numéricos, conceptualmente es algo así:

```
update tabla
    set campo1 = isnull(campo1,0),
    campo2 = isnull(campo2,0),
    ...
    campoN = isnull(campoN,0)
    WHERE campo1 IS NULL OR
          campo2 IS NULL OR
          ...
          campoN IS NULL
```

Ahora si tu pregunta apunta a que lo que no quieres es escribir los 97 campos, bueno se podría pero es bastante más complejo, habría que hacer una consulta dinámica, ver todos los campos numéricos de la tabla y construir una consulta  como la de arriba

En el caso de querer hacer una consulta dinámica, con esto se puede generar el Script, luego ejecutarlo con `sp_executesql`

```
DECLARE @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UPDATE     NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @WHERE      NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName  VARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @TableName  = 'NOMBRE_DE_TABLA'
SELECT  @UPDATE     = ''
SELECT  @WHERE      = ''

SELECT  @UPDATE = @UPDATE + '       ' + c.name + ' = ISNULL(' + c.name +',0),'  + CHAR(10),
    @WHERE  = @WHERE + '              OR ' + c.name + ' IS NULL'            + CHAR(10)
    FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.types t 
        ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    WHERE
            c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
        AND t.name IN ('tinyint','smallint','int','real','money','float',
                'decimal','numeric','smallmoney','bigint')



IF LEN(@UPDATE)> 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL =   'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET'         + CHAR(10) +
            '' + LEFT(@UPDATE,LEN(@UPDATE)-1)   + CHAR(10) +
            '       WHERE  1 = 2 '              + CHAR(10) +
            @WHERE
    PRINT @SQL
END
```

Aclaraciones

- No funciona con tablas tipo variables @Tabla
- Si, funciona con todo tipo de temporales, #Tabla o ##Tabla, pero hay que tener en cuenta que en estos casos hay que apuntar a las `sycolumns` y `systypes` de la Tempdb

Comment: Es exactamente lo que no quiero hacer hermano, tengo de esa forma alrededor de 4 tablas con el mismo detalle, no bajan de 90 campos por tabla. Por esa situación me gustaría algo mas complejo, es decir, que identifique sobre los valores de los campos de cualquier tabla y los reemplaze de null a '0'. Por ese motivo, les comentaba que es mas complejo de lo que me imaginaba.

Comment: Ojo porque a simple vista este query reemplazaria los valores de la tabla si esta tuvieras valores por ejemplo en el campo1 y el campo2 fueran null pondria 0 el campo1... el OR aca te mata...

Comment: No, no es así, el `campoN = isnull(CampoN,0)` solo modifica el valor si el campo es NULL, si no lo modifica pero por el mismo valor en todo caso.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, lo intente de otra manera, pero de todos modos la solución es buena. El problema es que todas las tablas están declaradas como variable de tabla y temporales. Gracias.